# A better condom user experience

Tags: user-behavior, physical, users, behavior-design

The lack of use of condoms is one of the most critical issues in global health today.  However the problems with condoms have little to do with how effective they are when used.  Instead the problems are mostly about people not using them due to a poor UX.

This problem has been highlighted recently by the [Gates' condom challenge](http://www.grandchallenges.org/Explorations/Topics/Pages/NextGenerationCondomRound11.aspx), which has already had at least one interesting entry with the [origami condom](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2306128/Collapsible-origami-condom-wins-praise-Bill-Melinda-Gates-Foundation.html).

[image: Origami condom]

So, what major UX factors are there for us to consider with condoms, and **what can we do to improve the UX of condoms** so that more people use them?

Comment: The tag "physical" suddenly gets a new meaning...

Comment: And there is the related issue of whether the condom packaging can be opened easily by a distracted user.

Comment: I'm not sure the article referenced really points the finger at UX here. It seems to be more of a PR/marketing issue.

Comment: @DA01 The Gates foundation has been clear that it's a UX issue, and I simply referring to one new approach as an example.

Comment: @JohnGB I read the article but don't see it pointing the finger at UX. Specifically, it says "lack of perceived incentive for consistent use" and then goes on to ask "Is it possible to develop a product without this stigma [of reduced sensitivity]?". Maybe they have found it to be a UX issue, but based on the referenced article, it sounds very much like a public relations issues. It's not that the condoms are hard to use, it's that they have an image problem.

Comment: @DA01 Literally billions of dollars have been spent on education and trying to change their image.  It has mostly not worked. I can't see how poor UX is not a major factor. Condoms are for the most part a UX failure, and if you speak to anyone in public health in the developing world, they will tell you just that.

Comment: @JohnGB I'm not necessarily disagreeing, but suggesting that be cited in the question somewhere, because the one article you are citing disagrees with your assumption.

Comment: @DA01 "The one major drawback to more universal use of male condoms is the lack of perceived incentive for consistent use. The primary drawback from the male perspective is that condoms decrease pleasure as compared to no condom, creating a trade-off that many men find unacceptable, particularly given that the decisions about use must be made just prior to intercourse.  Is it possible to develop a product without this stigma, or better, one that is felt to enhance pleasure?" from http://www.grandchallenges.org/Explorations/Topics/Pages/NextGenerationCondomRound11.aspx

Comment: @DA01 Therefore because of the bad user experience many men do/prefer not [to] use them.

Comment: @cpattersonv1 the issue, as you quote, is "lack of *perceived* incentive". To me, that sounds much more like a PR/marketing issue--not an issue with the product's *usability or actual experience of using*. The problem is getting people to use the condom in the first place--not that the physical act of using a condom is complicated. Arguably, we could stretch the definition of UX to cover that as well--but it seems to be a stretch. I certainly find it an interesting question--just not all that directly related to UX at this point.

Comment: @DA01 I can say that my desire not to use condoms is definitely not a marketing issue and it's very much a user experience issue. User experiences happen everywhere in any interaction between a user and something being used.

Comment: @cpattersonv1 The question as I see it is asking "How do we fix the user experience of a product that a customer doesn't want to obtain in the first place due to misconceptions?" While you may have UX gripes about the condom, I'm not seeing that in the quoted article above. (I'm just trying to improve the question being asked. I think it's a good question. It just needs more supporting material to tie it into the field of UX).

Comment: @DA01 it's not a misconception.  People try condoms.  The UX sucks. People stop using condoms.

Comment: @JohnGB I'm clearly not hitting my mark with my point. :) What I'm getting at is the reference you are using to support that statement says the problem is a "lack of perceived incentive". There are clear incentives (prevents you from disease and death!), so that would seem to be to be a big misconception. That seems to be a different problem than the actual experience of using the product. A product can be a lot of fun to use, but if there's no compelling argument for me to buy it, then the UX is a moot issue. It's now a sales/marketing challenge.

Comment: @DA01 A bad user experience with a condom can halt the whole reason for needing the condom in the first place. If there is an allergic reaction to the materials used in product, if there is a delay in being able to use the product (bad package), if the product tears during use, makes strange sounds, causes abrasions, or worse if the product is accidentally removed during use there were issues with the user experience. No amount of marketing is going to fix the risks associated with a condom coming off during intercourse. People do not use them for fear of the bad product design.

Comment: @cpattersonv1 those are all valid points! But the question doesn't include any of that data to make it an answerable question in that context. The question is referring to issues OTHER than those you listed--namely it's referring to the fact that people aren't using them in the first place due to perceptions. (I suggest you edit the question with those additions if you have citations you could include)

Comment: @DA01 I think it's covered under the blanket term "liabilities"... they're assuming (probably due to political correctness) that everyone is aware of the issue.

"Likewise, female condoms can be an effective method for prevention of unplanned pregnancy or HIV infection, but suffer from some of the same liabilities as male condoms..."

Comment: @DA01 at no point did I state that the question was about that article.  I merely stated that it highlights the need for a condom with a better UX.  I could remove that link and the question would remain the same.

Comment: @JohnGB perhaps that's my hangup. The article is perhaps adding confusion rather than clarity to the thesis.

Comment: The issue being neglected here is the stigma placed on condoms in many countries. Women who attempt to get their partner's to use condoms are, at best, shot down, and at worst, face physical violence in the face of such requests. This is obviously something that inhibits the use of condoms. It's good to remember that UX isn't just about design, it's also about understanding the cultural context in which your product is being used. http://www.who.int/gender/hiv_aids/en/

Comment: @DA01 directly from the article:  "Development and testing of new condom shapes/designs that may provide an improved ***user experience***" (emphasis mine)

Comment: Your premises are broken, it is not the UX, it is the stupidity by the users that is the problem. You wouldn't call it bad UX that a drunken driver crashes a car - sometimes it is not the UX but the user that is the problem. This is a typical example of that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I see three areas in which condoms experience can be improved:

- **Application** - for some people it may be difficult to apply a condom, especially if it's a very first time they use it (so that they don't know how to apply it) or she has long nails, which may cause perforation. Improving this part of condom use experience could be quite important.
- **Sexual (physical) experience** - The main thing about condoms is that they are considered rather as some distraction, not something that can actually improve the experience. However, they do address it somehow (and this regards boths sides) - there are condoms with lubricants or other substances extending the intercourse duration, special surfaces providing additional stimuli, etc. So, providing a shape that would lead to additional stimulation may be the trick. Changing the shape may also give some space for mounting some vibrating devides on the top of it.
- **Coolness** (except the sexual experience above) - condoms are not 'cool' - let's just say it. They grant more safety, of course, and this is something that actually influences the peace of the couple. But this is not 'coolness'. The coolness can be, however, applied by adding some extra features or great design. Funny, colorful condoms, sentences on them etc. may make people use them more often, but I believe this will mainly depend on perference of the couple. For both sides it may be essential to make the penis look bigger, more wild etc. Adding a tattoo pattern on it may help achieving it, as long as using some skeuporphic technique to make it look like it belonged to someone who by popular belief has higher sexual skills (e.g. making it brown or "sinewy" - not sure about the word). Or maybe Star Wars condoms? Why not? But most users will not focus on the condom **at all** I believe.
- **Education** - still, I believe the use of condoms ratio depends more on the awareness of what they provide and what is the cost of not using them. But this shifts the role even more towards creativity regarding packaging and promoting the use of them. It is possible to imbue the education with additional ideas ("Our condoms are eco." or "No animals were harmed..." disclaimer).

*By the way, the topic is quite sensitive, so please forgive me being inappropriate anywhere.*

Comment: If anyone ever makes a Star Wars condom, I hope it comes with the appropriate buzzy swooshing sound and glows in the dark.

Comment: @Rahul I believe I've seen glow-in-the-dark ones before...  And I'm sure most people have phones that could play the swooshing sound

Comment: "I'm not gonna be your father, Luke."

Comment: @Rahul Although people on the receiving end would dare not purchase it for fear of "the force being with you."

Answer (score 16):

Simply differentiating between the top and bottom of the rolled-up condom would really improve the UX in my opinion.

It can be difficult, especially in the low light environment these products are commonly used, to see which side is the entrance (see image below). If the condom is the wrong way around it won't roll on. Condoms are often stored for some time in their flat packet and they are flattened further by being stored in a wallet. This compression exacerbates the problem in distinguishing the condom's orientation.

Something as simple as colour coding the top and bottom of the rolled-up condom might help.

[image: Rolled up condom]

Comment: Very valid point.

Answer (score 5):

Think of it in terms of experience design. The use case is evident (for normal intended usage, that is).

Now, think of the user's cognitive faculties during the need of it. The base human needs trump the recently developed reasoning side of the brain. Imagine a frequent scenario, in the heat, due to reduced sound judgment, if the device (condom) does not function as intended on the first attempt, it increases frustration. It is acting as a barrier in that moment. Based on this we can outline some basic 'features' the condom should possess:

- **Affordances**: The design should be such that the application should be self evident. Look at the origami version which John posted. The unfolding nature of the condom makes the inside and outside differentiation quite evident by design. Even the packaging should be though about carefully.
- **Pleasurable experience**: In this case, the pleasure is quite literal. Even if the condom is designed flawlessly and works as intended. If the experience of coitus is not natural, it kills the purpose and motivation to use it again. This is the most important factor is retaining user-base. If the experience is good, people will have much less excuse of not using a condom. Coming up with a better material might be a key here.
- **Make it mainstream**: Smoking started as a class act back in the day due to it's promotion by the media and movies. Now, the same media has successfully converted it into something which is frowned upon. Something along these lines, [5 Basic Facts of Life (Were Made Up by Marketing Campaigns)](http://www.cracked.com/article_20324_5-basic-facts-life-were-made-up-by-marketing-campaigns.html). Look at how [purchasing hearing aids](http://www.kartendesign.com/research-driven/getting-inside-customers-heads/zon-s-series-with-sweep-technology/) was made into something trendy and socially accepted. We need a similar overhaul for the experience of buying not just condoms and emergency pills, but other health products which people feel uncomfortable doing in public locations. I agree with Dominik that education is the key here. But, I feel along with traditional sex education, we will receive much deeper impact if we have the mainstream media doing this. Currently, we do have many ad campaigns going advertising the importance and sexyness of condoms.

It is all about behavior design. Looking at BJ Fogg's behavior model:
[image]

When the motivation is high but the ability (ease of use) is low we can improve the target behavior (using condom) by making the ability easier. Vice versa, with easy ability and some motivation (can be achieved by marketing) we can increase the behavior too.

The thing to keep in mind is, many times, during the use case, the user is already riding a emotional motivation wave. If you are breaking that wave with your poor experience, you are making it harder for the user to turn this behavior into a habit. It should be as easy as removing the clothes, so to speak, you do not think about it per se, you know it's a necessary condition (most of the time) and does not take much effort. It fit's in perfectly with the act.

---

[The asterisk mark] My views are coming from having experienced multiple cultures ranging from fully developed societies to developing societies.

Answer (score 5):

- **Application time**: Condoms need to applicated while under high time pressure, since the erection may fall with every second, especially when performing a delicate and unsexy technical task as is applying a condom. As stated in other answers here, a flimsy packaging needs to be opened without damaging the contents, the correct orientation needs to be determined under possibly low lightning, the condom needs to be placed without encasing air and rolled down without slipping of again. I think faster application may greatly improve the usage ratio of condoms.

Comment: Benchmark: Read a paragraph describing the use of your condom without losing your erection.

Comment: Some may say it's the most critical of all UX issues :)

Comment: @rathernotsay Would you like to add your benchmark to the answer? :D

Answer (score 4):

Interesting case. I had never considered condoms from a UX perspective.
I have no firm opinions on the issue, I only wonder what the user research looks like in this case...

That aside, I'd like to point you to the 'condomerie' in Amsterdam. It is a brick and mortar condom shop (with [online presence](http://condomerie.com/)) that has managed to turn the purchase experience of condoms upside down. The shop is a major tourist attraction, and not only for visitors of the red light district. They've taken condoms out of the realms of porn and illnesses, to firmly place it in the world of fun, with a twist of seriousness. From a UX perspective, I'd say they did a remarkable job that should offer a lesson or two. 
[image]

Comment: I think that's a good example of improving the purchasing experience, though I'm not sure if it improved the overall user experience of the product itself.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try a slightly different approach to the answer: I'm not sure there are UX problems with condoms. They seem to be a fairly elegant solution to a host of more complex problems. They appear to be fairly self-explanatory once opened. Installation is usually trouble-free.

Now, granted, I've never participated in user testing or focus groups pertaining to the use of a condoms, so obviously I'd need more data to have specific answers.

But to get to that point, I'd try and determine what are actual problems vs. perceived problems. The article that is linked in the question talks about perceived problems. So it's apparent that there are also marketing challenges involved in attempting to increase the use of condoms.

If data shows that there are true physical challenges with the product, then focus would be spent more on improving the UX of the product. If data shows that it's more about perception, then perhaps we'd bring in the marketing department to assist.

I think one aspect of the condom using experience that could be improved is in obtaining the product. Great strides have been made in making them as readily available to those that want them, yet they are still often not the most pleasant product to obtain--especially if you are young. In the US, lots of places put the condoms front-and-center behind locked cabinets. This forces a younger person to deal with potentially awkward interactions with store staff in public. Perhaps one solution is go make sure young people have easier access to condoms (at least in the US, this then becomes less of a UX challenge and more of a political challenge).

In other regions of the world, it appears a major hurdle is education. Wiping away misconceptions about the products. This is likely more of a marketing/PR or Education challenge than UX. I'd first start doing a lot of user research with focus groups and interviews. Based on the data collected, one could then start to formulate education and marketing programs to target the key users.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not self-explanatory for much of their intended audience: http://vitals.nbcnews.com/_news/2012/02/26/10511064-condom-use-101-basic-errors-are-so-common-study-finds?lite

Answer (score 2):

Two major issues no-one has mentioned yet:

**Sensation:** Condoms don't feel as good as unprotected sex. There is less stimulation. This can potentially be a good thing (you last longer) but is often considered a very bad thing, and in the worst case can result in the user being unable to climax.

The problem seems to be that the condom covers the most sensitive parts of the penis and does not fully convey the sensation. This is more of a mechanical problem than a UX one, but is extremely important.

**Closeness** Having a physical barrier between you and your partner is off-putting so some people. It means that a person wanting to use a condom seems to be saying they don't want intimate contact, when in fact it may just be a question of contraception. Part of the thinking is that if it were just for contraception there are other reliable methods.

It doesn't help that condom use is also associated with protection from diseases, again suggesting that the person wanting to use them is afraid that their partner is unclean.